# Calling localhost:3000 on the browser after starting dagit returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: wsl-2, dagster

I have just started trying out dagster, I am already stumped at the first steps.

In [the guide](https://docs.dagster.io/getting-started/create-new-project) they specify:

> Then, start the Dagit web server:
>
> dagit
>
> Open http://localhost:3000 with your browser to see the project.
>
> Now, you can start writing assets in my_dagster_project/assets/, define your own ops or jobs and include them in my_dagster_project/repository.py.

Alright, I started dagit but I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I try to open it via the browser. Any ideas?

FYI, I am using WSL2.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working with a reboot.  It sounds like you ran into the same issue as [Localhost refused to connect on WSL2 when accessed via https://localhost:8000/ but works when using internal WSL IP adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926941/localhost-refused-to-connect-on-wsl2-when-accessed-via-https-localhost8000-b).  If so, would you accept the suggestion inthe header so this one gets closed out?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

This was a WSL2 port forwarding or localhost definition problem, nothing to do with dagster. I restarted my local machine and now it is working.

[image]