# how to go to a localhost using docker/docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Perhaps the question sounds vague and unclear. Now I will try to clarify the situation. I have a backend on Spring Boot and Postgresql. I am trying to deploy docker for development with a frontend developer. The containers are running, but I can't access the page either through the browser or through the postman.
Sorry for stupid question, that's my first time setting up Docker.

I've read "try to 0.0.0.0 or 172.18.0.1", but it doesn't work either.
And also, when i'm trying to specify ports (8181:8181 for example) Tomcat starts 8099 port.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
0cacf9541580   server-backend   "java -jar /server.j…"   6 minutes ago   Up 8 seconds   8089/tcp   server_container
7aa3902d97e6   postgres         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 8 seconds   5432/tcp   postgresql_container
```

Thats docker ps for this configuration

```
services:
  db:
#    ports:
#      - 5432:5432
    container_name: postgresql_container
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=midas_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: server_container
#    ports:
#      - 8181:8181
#    extra_hosts:
#      - "host.docker.internal:172.18.0.1"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL_DOCKER}
      - spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
      - spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

```
 ONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
    58b63f2cc3b3   server-backend   "java -jar /server.j…"   11 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds    8089/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8181->8181/tcp   server_container
    ed5efdfc4cf4   postgres         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             postgresql_container
```

Thats for this configuration

```
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: postgresql_container
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=midas_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: server_container
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
#    extra_hosts:
#      - "host.docker.internal:172.18.0.1"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL_DOCKER}
      - spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
      - spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.9.5-openjdk-11-slim
LABEL maintainer="matushkin-2017@mail.ru"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8181
ARG JAR_FILE=target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/server.jar"]
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) are you sure the web backend is running on port 8181 (2) what is running on port 8009?

Comment: when i start application without using docker, it works fine on 8181
And nothing is running on port 8009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to launch docker and connect to the localhost.
What did I do:

1. I've installed **Ubuntu** as a second system
2. Rewrote the docker-compos and docker file as attached below.
3. Changed one of the environment variables.

i had: `DB_URL_DOCKER=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:postgres@pghost:5433/midas_db`

now i have: `DB_URL_DOCKER=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/midas_db`
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
LABEL maintainer="matushkin-2017@mail.ru"
EXPOSE 8181
ARG JAR_FILE=target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/server.jar"]
```

here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    container_name: postgresql_container
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=midas_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: server_container
    ports:
      - 8181:8181
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL_DOCKER}
      - spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
      - spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

**Thank you so much for your help, @Tschösi**

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing this answer to summarize what we found out so far (see comments below).

- The tomcat server runs on port `8099` (`bash-4.4# curl "http://127.0.0.1:8099"` within the container reaches the server)

Now please perform the following troubleshooting steps (we will move inwards out).

1. Adapt your `Dockerfile` to expose the correct port (shouldn't be strictly necessary as we publish the port through compose, but might have an impact on the firewall):

```
FROM maven:3.9.5-openjdk-11-slim
LABEL maintainer="matushkin-2017@mail.ru"
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8099
ARG JAR_FILE=target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/server.jar"]
```

2. Adapt your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: postgresql_container
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=midas_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: server_container
    ports:
      - "8181:8099"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL_DOCKER}
      - spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
      - spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

3. restart your application `docker-compose up --build backend` (or `docker compose up --build backend`, depending on your compose version)
4. Check whether you can reach the server in the docker container `docker exec server_container curl http://localhost:8099/api/v1/midas/category`
5. Check whether you can reach the server from within WSL. **In a WSL console** execute `curl http://localhost:8181/api/v1/midas/category` (we mapped 8099 to 8181).
6. Check whether you can reach the server from your host system (Windows). Open `http://localhost:8181/api/v1/midas/category` in a browser.

Please let me know in the comments at which step your problem occurs.

Comment: I tried it, but i have the same issue. Chrome says:
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Okay, so to debug this, can you check from *within* the container which port is actually used? `docker exec -it server_container bash` and then `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8181`" or `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8089"`?

Comment: here is my console output 
1) `bash-4.4# curl "http://127.0.0.1:8181"`
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8181: Connection refused`
2) `bash-4.4# curl "http://127.0.0.1:8089"`
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8089: Connection refused`
3) `bash-4.4# curl "http://127.0.0.1:8099"`
`{"timestamp":"2024-01-22T12:06:41.374+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/"}`

Comment: Alright, so this looks like the server is running on port `8099` (although there seems to be nothing on the root path - but that is another issue). Can you set the port mapping to `- 8181:8099` and then try to access in the browser `http://127.0.0.1:8181`? If you get a `404`, you are conecting to your backend (might need to check some endpoint that has something running)

Comment: I have installed ports: - 8181:8099. Neither ttp://127.0.0.1:8181, nor http://127.0.0.1:8099 It doesn't work. I've checked my endpoints and they work fine without docker. But when I launch docker, I get the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: interesting fact: when i run `exec -it server_container bash` , then `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8099/api/v1/midas/category"` i get `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
[{"id":1,"name":"First one!"},{"id":4,"name":"4 category"},{"id":3,"name":"3 category"},{"id":2,"name":"2 category"},{"id":103,"name":"5 category"}]`

So, it works. But when i try send request using postman or browser i get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8099

Comment: Which operating system are you using? If you are using Windows this might be a firewall issue.

Comment: Yes, i'm using windows and wsl Ubuntu

Comment: Can you try the following: add `hostname: "0.0.0.0"` to your server_container config (same level as `container_name`)? And then try again to access it from outsite the container (Port `8181` if you left the `docker-compose.yml` as is). **If that doesn't work**, try to access your api via `http://[::1]:8181`.

Comment: i get`curl "http://[::1]:8099/api/v1/midas/category"
[{"id":1,"name":"First one!"},{"id":4,"name":"4 category"},{"id":3,"name":"3 category"},{"id":2,"name":"2 category"},{"id":103,"name":"5 category"}]` and `curl "http://0.0.0.0:8099/api/v1/midas/category"
[{"id":1,"name":"First one!"},{"id":4,"name":"4 category"},{"id":3,"name":"3 category"},{"id":2,"name":"2 category"},{"id":103,"name":"5 category"}]` in console. But in doesn't work with port 8181 and it doesn't work in postman at all. Neither `http://[::1]:`, nor `0.0.0.0:`

Comment: Are you using "normal" docker or docker desktop?

Comment: I have docker desktop installed, but I run everything using the console. Is this considered to be using a "normal" docker or is it more of a docker desktop?

Comment: There are two possible points of failure here. Between Windows and WSL and between WSL and docker.
Can you confirm whether or not the curl command is able to connect from the WSL console? (So `curl http://localhost:8181/api/v1/category` in **WSL**)

Comment: Yes, I used WSL to execute this command. Everything is working in WSL

Comment: Okay, then the problem is not with docker but the connection to WSL. Can you try to `wsl --shutdown` to restart the whole thing? (Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70004971/9903391)

Comment: I don't really know what is happening here. Nothing helps. This method didn't work either

Comment: @1dlvb I edited my answer, please check it again.